# SQL get the same day from last year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to get the current date from a datetime. I understand that the best way to do this is by

```
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

however if i am trying to get the equivalent day from last year, am I better off doing

Solution 1

```
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), -365)
```

OR Solution 2

```
DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Are there any times at which Solution 1 wouldn't work?

Comment: Not an answer, hence the comment, make sure you're clear with users on the expectations around leap days.

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, you may want to define what 'works' means to you.  I don't think either will error out, but which answer is right depends on the requirements.

Comment: I think you may have hit the nail on the head!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution 2 automatically subtracts 366 days for leap years.

Solution 1 doesn't; you might get the succeeding day, if a leap year is involved.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the current date from a `datetime`, since SQL Server 2008, is:

```
CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
```

The best way to subtract a year is to use either `YEAR` or `MONTH`:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, -12, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE))
```

Not all days have 365 days, so that would be an inappropriate calculation.

Comment: What would happen if you were then comparing this to a datetime? would it not then cast it back? Would this have performance issues/gains?

Comment: @Henry . . . `date` and `datetime` can be compared to each other (the date is converted to a `datetime`).  There really isn't any performance implication.  In fact, `cast(. . . as date)` is even sargable -- perhaps the only "function" that is.